# problem with searching a sting containing some Letters using mysql query

Tags: mysql

i want to search a column data contain some letters like OP or OPS.

```
desp
--------
 9037OP

 3HTVOPS

 G4OP568H

select * from table WHERE desp LIKE '%OP' OR '%OPS' order by desp desc
```

if try this query its returned only '9037OP'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct query should be

This is when `OP` and `OPS` shoule be found only at the end of the string

```
select * from table `desp` WHERE `desp` LIKE '%OP' OR `desp` LIKE '%OPS' order by `desp` desc
```

and for `OP`, `OPS` anywhere in the string

```
select * from table `desp` WHERE `desp` LIKE '%OP%' OR `desp` LIKE '%OPS%' order by `desp` desc
```

Comment: check with the above query now

Comment: i have just given only 2 kind of patterns in this, but there where around min 40 to 200 such a patters ends here .so i can't add around 200 like statement to that .

Comment: Think you'll need [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)